# Share on Facebook Image+AppLink Android

Tags: android, facebook, image, hyperlink, share

I have an app that enables users to share images on facebook; I'd like that automatically the link of the app could be shared together with the image.

This is the code I'm using but the part with the link is just ignored and doesn't appear:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/png");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.google.com"); //doesn't appear
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList)
{

    Log.d("CitationsManager-ShareOnFb", app.activityInfo.name);
    if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook.katana")
        || (app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook.composer.shareintent")
        || (app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook.composer.activity"))
    {
        final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
        final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(
            activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
        shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        shareIntent.setComponent(name);
        context.startActivity(shareIntent);
        break;
    }
```

Do you have any idea how I can get the result? I've read questions on the topic but couldn't find a suitable solution.

Thanks

Comment: I also have almost similar requriement. Have you got a solution for the same?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook provides shareDialog class to share images or content on facebook. You can read more details, check [here](https://www.studytutorial.in/android-share-images-or-content-to-facebook-from-android-application-tutorial-using-facebook-sdk)

```
     shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);  // initialize facebook shareDialog.
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
         ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
             .setContentTitle("Android Facebook Integration and Login Tutorial")
             .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.studytutorial.in/
                   wp-content/uploads/2017/02/FacebookLoginButton-min-300x136.png"))
             .setContentDescription(
                     "This tutorial explains how to integrate Facebook and Login 
                     through Android Application")
             .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.studytutorial.in/
                         android-facebook-integration-and-login-tutorial"))
             .build();
                shareDialog.show(linkContent);  // Show facebook ShareDialog
       }
    }
});
```